# Page works in IE and FF but not in Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari

Can someone tell me what I could be doing wrong.  The following page works fine in IE8 and FireFox but elements of the CSS don't seem to be being respected in Chrome and Safari.  Thanks.

page at:
http://www.diabetesgoaltracker.com/home.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

First, the div `#navigation` that wraps around the ul `#navlist` is redundant.  Just style the ul like you would the div and lose the div altogether.

Secondly, I would make the ul float left.  Then I would make the content div float left and lose the margins.  Make sure `#container` is `overflow:hidden;`  As long as you set the width of the ul and the content div, it should look good in all browsers.

I'm actually baffled that it looks the way it does in Chrome...  I'll update this answer as I examine it more.

*UPDATE*

The user agent in chrome styles the ul `display: block;`  You should add a reset stylesheet to put all browsers on the same footing.  Although, if you follow my above advice that will not be a direct issue.  Let me know if you need set of reset rules I use.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the original question but if I remove the DOCTYPE line (which I know is a no-no), it works fine in everything except IE8 where I appear to have a clear/float issue, the content on the right starting after end of the navigation on the left.

Comment: You should heed Computerish's answer and check your server configuration.

Comment: I ended the DOCTYPE with a /> instead of > and everything appears to be fine in all browsers.  I agree that is must be a server issue.

Comment: I checked and the content-type of the css is still `*/*` instead of `text/css`.  You should look into fixing that even if things look okay presently.  This will only give you more headaches down the road.

Comment: Thanks.  Will do.  I was hoping that you'd check that again.

Comment: my "fix" appeared to have addressed the outrageous behavior of not respecting some of the CSS elements however IE6 and IE7 which I didn't immediately test, were still a problem - fooling around with the widths, as you suggested, fixed those browsers as well.  Your first suggestion above as you said was to address redundancy - I initially did it and worked fine, the second suggestion looked like it would have worked with some tweaking of widths but it messed up my other pages (using the same CSS) royally so since everything  worked, I just put the original CSS back to look at another day.

Answer (score 1):

When I validate your CSS with W3's CSS validator I get this error:

```
I/O Error: Unknown mime type : */*
```

This could indicate a server error which is throwing Chrome off. Check out this thread:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=461039

(Also check through your css. You have div#navigation in there where it should just be #navigation.)

Comment: I didn't get that error.  I got Congratulations...validates as CSS level 2.1.  Could someone else try please.

Comment: When I inspect my headers I definitely get a content type `*/*` instead of content type `text/css` so this is correct.